# WPF Binding to custom DependencyProperty - IsChecked is sometimes opposite value of property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a control in WPF derived from UserControl. The control has a Dependency property named `IsDraggable`. It's implemented like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDraggableProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsDraggable), typeof(bool), typeof(MyUserControl));
public bool IsDraggable
{
    get { return (bool)this.GetValue(IsDraggableProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(IsDraggableProperty, value); }
}

private void IsDraggableMenuItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => this.IsDraggable = !this.IsDraggable;
```

In the XAML, there is a ContextMenu for the UserControl:

```
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <!-- other menu items here -->
        <MenuItem
            Header="Draggable"
            IsCheckable="True"
            Click="IsDraggableMenuItemClick"
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyUserControlsNameProperty, ElementName=IsDraggable}" />
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
```

Using this UserControl, I have added one into the main window, and one inside the outer UserControl. In the outer control, the checkable `MenuItem` works like expected, but in the inner one, it's checked when `IsDraggable` is false, and unchecked when it's true.

What could cause this?

Comment: Perhaps just remove the Click handler from the MenuItem. Setting IsCheckable to true and binding IsChecked should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the `IsDraggable` property explicitly in an event handler? You should either bind the `IsChecked` property of the `MenuItem` to your `UserControl` property:

```
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <!-- other menu items here -->
        <MenuItem
            Header="Draggable"
            IsCheckable="True"
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.IsDraggable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
```

*Or* handle the `Checked` and `Unchecked` eventw of the `MenuItem`:

```
<MenuItem
    Header="Draggable"
    IsCheckable="True"
    Checked="MenuItem_Checked" Unchecked="MenuItem_Unchecked" />
```

---

```
private void MenuItem_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.IsDraggable = false;
}

private void MenuItem_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.IsDraggable = true;
}
```

But not both.